# Need to return a value for a parent function - python

Tags: python, function, tkinter, return, parent

I'm using python 2.7.5 on mac OSX

in my code I have a function that needs to return a value. Within the function I want my callback function (tkinter) to make it's parent function to return a value, but if there is a better way to do this please say. Sorry if I'm being un-clear because I'm not sure how to explain my problem.

```
def Open():
    class dataC:
        lines=[]
    data=dataC


    def event():
        path=pathE.get()
        file=fileE.get()

        try:
            os.chdir(path)

            temp=open(file)
            lines=temp.readlines()
            temp.close()
        except:
            lines=[]
        else:
            os.chdir(path)

            temp=open(file)
            lines=temp.readlines()
            temp.close()

        data.lines=lines


    gui=Tk()
    gui.title("Open File")

    pathE=Entry(gui)
    pathE.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
    pathE.insert(INSERT,startingDir)

    fileE=Entry(gui)
    fileE.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
    fileE.insert(INSERT,"File Name")

    openE=Button(gui,text="Open File",command=event)
    openE.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
    gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: So why don't you just use `return something_to_return`?

Comment: @nabla Because event (The function in which I get the value that I need to return) is a callback function

Comment: And where do you want to pass the return value if not to the calling function?

Comment: I need the parent function (Open()) to return the value, but the value isn't created until the callback function is run. So I can't just add >return stuff

Comment: Where is your mainloop?

Comment: at the end, missed it when I pasted my code in.

Comment: And what do you want to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to return a value in `Open()` I assume that the mainloop should be quit as soon as the button is clicked. So you have to add the line

```
gui.quit()
```

or

```
gui.destroy()
```

in `event()`. You can save the value you want to return in a local variable of `Open()` while you are in `event()`, like you already do with `data` and then return it after the `mainloop` line.